# how to create direct display randomly number

Tags: javascript, html, css, blogger, blogspot

I want to ask, how to make this script directly display the total of numbers on my blog post without clicked, And will change if browser is refreshed.

```
` http://jsfiddle.net/BenedictLewis/xmPgR/
```

Comment: You are generating a random number within a particular range and you are not saving the numbers to calculate its sum. So what sum are you exactly referring here to?

Comment: Links to jsfiddle must be accompanied by code. Post your code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There the problem is, your getNumber() function is executing only after click. There is no way it is not added to on load part.

One simple way is call the function getNumbers() after declaration as i did:

```
var link = document.getElementById('getNumber'); // Gets the link
link.onclick = getNumber; // Runs the function on click

function getNumber() {
    var minNumber = 0; // The minimum number you want
    var maxNumber = 100; // The maximum number you want
    var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxNumber + 1) + minNumber); // Generates random number
    $('#myNumber').html(randomnumber); // Sets content of <div> to number
    return false; // Returns false just to tidy everything up
}
getNumber(); // here i called the method, it runs on load of the script
             //and works as you wanted
```

Comment: @Andre Let me know if this is what you were looking for?